# Mustache - Template Organization

Tags: mustache

I recently discovered Mustache, and after reading through all the documentation online, I am still having trouble understanding how to use it.  I am not sure how to separate my HTML from my template file, as I understand you include your tags within a variable in your javascript file.

I am creating a site where I would like to have a header/footer function.  I turned to mustache to do this.

Here is my current template:

```
template = "
{{#head}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <script src = "extras/icomoon/lte-ie7.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en"> <!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.5.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/respond.js/1.1.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectivizr/1.0.2/selectivizr-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexie/1.0.0/flexie.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/move.js"</script>
<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- Use the .htaccess and remove these lines to avoid edge case issues.
         More info: h5bp.com/i/378 -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

     <title>{title}</title>
    <meta name="description" content="{meta-description}">

    <!-- Mobile viewport optimized: h5bp.com/viewport -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

    <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory: mathiasbynens.be/notes/touch-icons -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Erica+One|Ubuntu+Condensed|Open+Sans|Maven+Pro|Sans+Pro:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/base.css">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet/less" href="less/style.less"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animations.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/typography.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/no-flexbox.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">
   <!-- <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/1140.css"> -->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/media-queries.css">
    <!-- todo: add font-awesome and icomoon-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="extras/icomoon/style.css">
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.5.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tests/tests.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/chosen.css">

    <!-- More ideas for your <head> here: h5bp.com/d/head-Tips -->

    <!-- All JavaScript at the bottom, except this Modernizr build.
         Modernizr enables HTML5 elements & feature detects for optimal performance.
         Create your own custom Modernizr build: www.modernizr.com/download/ -->

</head>
{{/head}}
<body>
    <!-- Prompt IE 6 users to install Chrome Frame. Remove this if you support IE 6.
         chromium.org/developers/how-tos/chrome-frame-getting-started -->
    <!--[if lt IE 7]><p class="chromeframe">Your browser is <em>ancient!</em> <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">Upgrade to a different browser</a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a> to experience this site.</p><![endif]-->

    <!-- Add your site or application content here -->
    <header id="main" class="main-menu loading">
        {{#logo}}<a href = "/index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" class="flash-hover"></img></a>{{/logo}}
        {{#nav}}<nav id="nav-main" class="top-menu">
            <ul class = "top-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="docs/about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="docs/features.html">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="docs/installation.html">Installation</a></li>
                <li><a href="help-support/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>{{/nav}}
    </header>
    <div id="ajaxloader1"></div>
    <div id="main-content" role = "main" class = "loading">
    {{#top_a}}
    <div id="top-a">
    {{content}}
    </div>{{/top_a}}
    {{#article}}
    <article>
    <hgroup>
        <h1 class="article-header">{{header}}</h1>
        <h2 class="subtitle">{{subtitle}}</h2>
        </hgroup>
        {{content}}
    </article>
    {{/article}}

    {{#footer}}
    <!-- JavaScript at the bottom for fast page loading: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom -->

    <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if offline -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    <!-- scripts concatenated and minified via build script -->
    <!-- <script src="js/plugins.js"></script> -->
    <script src="js/loading.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hashgrid/6/hashgrid.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/store.js/1.1.1/store.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kerning.js/0.2/kerning.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/2.1.04/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.0.4/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.transit/0.1.3/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="extras/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/vendor/can.jquery.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.5.0-dev/mustache.min.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/vendor/can.fixture.js"></script> -->
    <script src = "js/main.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.19/jquery-ui.min.js" media = "@screen"></script> -->
    <!-- end scripts -->

    <!-- Asynchronous Google Analytics snippet. Change UA-XXXXX-X to be your site's ID.
         mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet -->
    <!-- <script>
        var _gaq=[['_setAccount','UA-XXXXX-X'],['_trackPageview']];
        (function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
        g.src=('https:'==location.protocol?'//ssl':'//www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)}(document,'script'));
    </script> -->
</body>
</html>
{{/footer}}

";
```

The problem I get is obviously that I need to escape all the quotation marks.  So my question is, what's the best way of separating all this markup from the template so that I can still get my syntax highlighting as if I was doing inline html in PHP, with standard header/footer functions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't multi-line strings in JS, so you can't just throw all of that in a JS string if that's what that's supposed to be. Ordinarily I'd suggest perhaps putting it in a `<script>` element like this:

```
<script type="text/x-mustache-template">

{{#head}}
<!DOCTYPE html>

...

</script>
```

But since you have `<script>` tags in your template, that's not so straightforward. Your best bet might be to put the template in it's own file, and pull it into your page with PHP, something like:

```
<?php

$templates = array();

$template[ 'whatever' ] = file_get_contents( "template.mustache" );

?>

<script>

var templates = <?php echo json_encode( $templates ); ?>;

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Unfortunately, PHP isn't an option at the moment.  Can you provide an example of how to do this in javascript, using mustache.js?

Comment: Is it an option to store the template in a separate file and pull it in via ajax? If not, then the most readable thing might be to put it in a `<script>` tag as illustrated in the first snippet in my answer, and escape the `</script>` end tags that are part of the template. I'm not sure off hand if there's a more legit way to accomplish that, so for the time being I'd suggest replacing some part of it with a mustache variable that that will either evaluate to empty string, or to part of the actual end tag, e.g. `</{{empty}}script>`, or `</{{script}}>` where `{{script}}` echoes "script".

Comment: Thanks again.  I am interested in the ajax method, and I've done some searching, but am still confused.  Using this method, do I take my existing template (minus the ``var template =``), and store it in a file called ``template.mustache``... or is that only for partials?  I understand how to make an ajax call in jQuery, so my real concern here is the organization.  I can call the ``Mustache.to_html(template, data)`` function to get the rendered html from the file... is that the best solution?

Comment: Yeah, I'd take the whole thing minus the `var template =` and store it in a file called `template.mustache`, or whatever you want. The important thing is to have it accessible via a URL that will return it as text/plain or text/html. I'm not famliar with `Mustache.to_html()`, I'd just retrieve the template via Ajax and then call `Mustache.render( template, data )`. I think that should work, but haven't tried it. Post back how it turns out.